# How could i reach textBox value in ajax method?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have two problem. First one, when i click Log In button, localhost wants to me give allow. but it suddenly disappear in one second. if i double click, it always shows in the bottom like this. then Ajax method run. i want to show this windows always in one click.

My second problem, i want to reach txtUserName in ajax method. i don't know how to this.

[image: error]

Code Behind :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string SendLocation(object Latitude, object Longitude)
    {
        Core dal_ = new Core();
        Model.Team obj_ = new Model.Team();

        //obj_.UserName = ?????
        obj_.Latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(Latitude);
        obj_.Longitude = Convert.ToDecimal(Longitude);

        dal_.UpdateTeamCoordinat(obj_);
        return "";
    }
```

JavaScript (in asp.x) :

```
   <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/yqlgeo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initiate_geolocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query, handle_errors);
        }
        else {
            yqlgeo.get('visitor', normalize_yql_response);
        }
    }

    function handle_errors(error) {
        switch (error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");
                break;

            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");
                break;

            case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timedout");
                break;

            default: alert("unknown error");
                break;
        }
    }

    function normalize_yql_response(response) {
        if (response.error) {
            var error = { code: 0 };
            handle_error(error);
            return;
        }

        var position = {
            coords:
        {
            latitude: response.place.centroid.latitude,
            longitude: response.place.centroid.longitude
        },
            address:
        {
            city: response.place.locality2.content,
            region: response.place.admin1.content,
            country: response.place.country.content
        }
        };
        handle_geolocation_query(position);     
    }

    function handle_geolocation_query(position) {
        PageMethods.SendLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }
</script>
```

Asp.x:

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Log In"    OnClientClick="initiate_geolocation()"
                OnClick="LoginButton_Click" />
```

Comment: What Ajax method in which your want to reach txtUserName?

Comment: in codebehind, SendLocation ajax method

Comment: Where this webmethod is requested in your code?

Comment: in Javascript, this row :     PageMethods.SendLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying to select an element in a webMethod? i would think that would be impossible

I mostly use WebMethods as FireAndForget type functions.

if you wanted to select the textbox after firing the function then I would select it using javaScript

```
function handle_geolocation_query(position) {
    PageMethods.SendLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

   //If have JQuery
   var textbox = $('#' + <%=txtUserName.ClientID %>);

   //otherwise
   document.getElementById(<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>);    
}
```

depending on what you wanted to do with the element depends whether to bother with the JQuery root.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your ajax call to:

```
PageMethods.SendLocation($("#txtUserName").val(), position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
```

You also need to add it as a parameter to your webmethod too.